# Keeping source as a copy in destination class using Automapper

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper, automapper-5

Is there a way to keep the entire source object as a copy in my destination class as a property..

e.g.

Source:

```
class SourceClass
{
    prop string Prop1 { get; set; }
    prop string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Destination:

```
class DestinationClass
{
    prop string Prop1 { get; set; }
    prop string Prop2 { get; set; }
    prop SourceClass SourceClassCopy { get; set; }
}
```

and using automapper configuration something like

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
        cfg.ReplaceMemberName("this", "SourceClassCopy");
        cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(); //or .ForMember("SourceClassCopy", d => d.MapFrom(s => s));
   });
```

Why I am doing this is coz I am having a hierarchical object and would like to keep a copy for reverse mapping as the Source class doesn't have a default constructor that will help me reverse map. Also the source class is in a library that I can't modify :( and has methods/functions that accept entire source object. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public SourceClass SourceClassCopy { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var source = new SourceClass();
        source.Prop1 = "Prop1Source";
        source.Prop2 = "Prop2Source";

        var destination = new DestinationClass();
        destination.Prop1 = "Prop1Dest";
        destination.Prop2 = "Prop2Dest";

        var sourceinDest = new SourceClass();
        sourceinDest.Prop1 = "Prop1sourceinDest";
        sourceinDest.Prop2 = "Prop2sourceinDest";
        destination.SourceClassCopy = sourceinDest;

        // Configure AutoMapper
        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SourceClassCopy, m=>m.MapFrom(src=>src));

        Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(source, destination);


        Console.WriteLine(destination.Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(destination.Prop2);
        Console.WriteLine(destination.SourceClassCopy.Prop1);       
        Console.WriteLine(destination.SourceClassCopy.Prop2);       
    }
}
```